# Robot Framework - performing multiple keywords after running keyword if

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to execute multiple keywords if a condition evaluates as true.

I tried to do something like this

```
 *** Test Cases ***
| Example

 *** Keywords ***
| Example
|  | ${title}=  Get Title
|  | Run Keyword If      | '${title}' == 'Some Title' 
|  | ... Click Element   |  xpath=some element 
|  | ... Element Text Should Be  |   xpath=some element   |  some text
|  | ... Else
|  | ... Click Element   | xpath=other element
```

The error I get when running this is that the Click Element expects 1 argument but gets 4.

I know that I can set the if statement in the Test cases section and if evaluated true it will run a keyword with all the stuff I want but I wonder if there is a way to do it from the Keywords section.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do a couple of things. The first is to create a new keyword that calls all the other keywords, and then call that from `Run keyword if`. This might be the most readable solution, but at the expense of having to write and document another keyword.

The other choice is to use a combination of `Run keyword if` and `Run keywords`, like so:

```
| | Run Keyword if | '${title}' == 'Some Title'
| | ... | Run Keywords
| | ... | Click Element | xpath=some element
| | ... | AND | Element Text Should Be  |  xpath=some element | some text
| | ... | ELSE
| | ... | Click Element | xpath=other element
```

Comment: When using `Run Keywords` make sure to use capital `AND` (needed when using keywords with arguments as per documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Run keywords does not take keywords with arguments so you cannot use this.Option is to create keyword for all statements below Run keywords and call it.
https://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run 
--User keywords must nevertheless be used if the executed keywords need to take arguments.

Comment: _"Run keywords does not take keywords with arguments"_ - that is not a true statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use IF END construct instead of "Run keyword If" to run multiple keywords without much hustle.

Example:

```
IF    '${skip}' == 'True'
    Log    This prints this line
    ${count} =    Evaluate    ${count} + 1
    IF    '${count}' == ${10}
        Log     Value of count: ${count}. Resetting ${skip}
        ${skip}    Set Variable    ${False}    
    END
END
```